# Is it possible to call on extension commands directly from terminal instead of using the command pallet?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Im trying out an unnsuported extension in vscode that has limited possibilites.
One of the extension capabilties includes pulling files from a software and to the vscode enviroment. This is done by calling an extension command inside command pallet; "extensionname.Extension.getlib". It then prompts and demands an input where to get get data from and the specific file. This works but i have to do this step 1000 times to get all the files needed.

So my question is as follows: Is it possible to somehow call the extension command directly from the terminal instead of command pallet or make a script that calls on it?(Instead of rewriting the code for the extension) For example:

Callextension_command("extensionname.Extension.getlib(Paramater1:"Enviroment", Parameter2: "ExampleFile")

Comment: use the extension `multi-command`, create a combi command with a python/JavaScript script, or write an extension that calls the `extensionname.Extension.getlib` and fetches the parameters from a file you specify

Comment: Thanks alot for an answer! I will have to test it out :)